# Eclipse CDT 5.x and cmake 2.6.x

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, eclipse-cdt

According to what I see, cmake 2.6.x supports CDT 4.x. We already have CDT 6.x.
Is CDT 5.x and cmake 2.6.x are compatible at least?

Thanks
Dima

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is.

The eclipse CDT 4.x project generated by cmake is compatible with next versions.

I use them everyday, and work like a charm:

- cmake: version 2.6-patch 2 (Ubuntu 8.10)
- eclipse: version 3.4.1
- CDT: version 5.0.1

I have also tried to import those projects with CDT 6 and all it keep working. Would be really bad if you were not be able to reuse projects from old versions. Backward compatibility is really important for serious applications.

Comment: Do you have a reference to it? :)

Comment: It's pity that the answer to the question is just trying and hope that it won't fail :) Here is one more brave person using CDT 6 http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-August/031124.html

Comment: Think this is not a cuestion about a cmake feature but about eclipse CDT projects backward compatibility

Comment: @fnieto You're right.

According to answer of one of the cmake maintainers (http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-August/031131.html) CDT 5/6 probably fine with cmake 2.6.x